# Forcing Rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 onto 2.4Ghz WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I'm looking to force my Samsung to use the 2.4Ghz range of our Wifi as I need it to setup another device. The problem is the SSID for the 5Ghz and the 2.4Ghz is the same.

Does anyone know of a way to block the 5Ghz range so only the 2.4 Works?

Thanks
CRFC11

Comment: Have you checked the WiFi (advanced) settings for the AP? I don't know if its valid for all devices, but at least some have an entry here for "preferred band" or the like, where you can chose between 2.4 and 5GHz.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy I had a look and couldn't see that option only the auto switch function :/

Answer (score 1):

I needed to be connected to 2.4ghz to connect to my robotic lawn mower to wifi and set it up. Tried everything to no avail. Finally I walked outside to a range that the 5ghz would no longer be good and the tablet automatically connected to the 2.4ghz signal. Then I was able to do the setup. Voila! I don't have an answer to change it forever but that worked for the little setup I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the SSID for the 5GHz and the 2.4GHz network is the same, it probably means that the connection is handled by the router/access-point. Hence, you should look into the configuration of the router/access-point, to see how it selects the channel to connect to.

Comment: The solution needs to be on the device side not router. As the Meraki's are set for 5Ghz priority which is the company standard. Thanks anyway @Orpedo